# How to lowercase the capture group only in scala

Tags: regex, scala, replaceall

This code:

```
"""{"nAMe": "Deloise", "WINS": [["three of a kind", "5♣"]]}""".replaceAll("""(\"[^"]+\" *:)""", "|UPERCASETEST|$1|".toLowerCase())
```

Produces :

```
String = {|upercasetest|"nAMe":| "Deloise", |upercasetest|"WINS":| [["three of a kind", "5♣"]]}
```

While I was expecting :

```
String = {|upercasetest|"name":| "Deloise", |upercasetest|"wins":| [["three of a kind", "5♣"]]}
```

Any idea on why the capture group does not wish to lowercase and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the match object to a lambda expression inside `replaceAllIn` where you may manipulate the contents, otherwise, inside `replaceAll`, the `$1` does not get "expanded" to the actual Group 1 submatch value:

```
val s = """{"nAMe": "Deloise", "WINS": [["three of a kind", "5♣"]]}"""
val rx = """(\"[^"]+\" *:)""".r
val replacedStr = rx replaceAllIn (s, m => s"|UPERCASETEST|${m.group(1)}|".toLowerCase())
println(replacedStr)
```

See [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/xbP1ZO)

Output:

```
{|upercasetest|"name":| "Deloise", |upercasetest|"wins":| [["three of a kind", "5♣"]]}
```